# mySQL Connection in Amazon web server

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect mySQL through my AWS EC2.

But it doesn't work when I try to access this page.
This error message comes up.

'This page isn’t working

18.221.###.92 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500'

Here is my simple code for the connection.

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$passWord = '#####';
$dbName = 'member';

$dbConnect = new mysqli($host,$user,$passWord,$dbName);

if($dbConnect){
  echo "MySQL Connection success.";
}
else{
  echo "MYSQL Connection failed.";
}
 ?>
```

I uploaded this php file using Filezila.

It works well when I try to access my own web server( ex)Bitnami)
But it doesn't work in AWS EC2.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of issues is alot easier to debug if you separate the different components that could be at fault here. First try to connect to the RDS instance using a mysql shell on the EC2 instance, and after you make sure it works - proceed to debug your PHP code.

Instructions for connecting to RDS can be found here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

Comment: thanks I solved this problem,
It was because I didn't install mysql on my web server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention RDS URL which you can find in AWS portal.

[image]

Then replace $host = 'localhost'; with $host = 'RDS_Endpoint_url';